# What is the purpose of the <html> element?

Tags: html

Doesn't the file type already let the browser know that the document is an html document. MDN mentions that it is the root element, so is using it just a formality?

Comment: https://w3c.github.io/html/semantics.html#the-html-element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a family trait of HTML, XML, and SGML that they all need to be nested inside a root element. It's just part of the data standard and lets the interpreter know where to start and stop, and verifies that the document is complete and well-formed.

`<!DOCTYPE html>` specifies the type of document. In that case it means that it is HTML 5 currently, as opposed to XML or XHTML 1.0 transitional, as examples. Keep in mind that if you are downloading these as byte streams you may not always know the file type.

Comment: Additionally HTML can be rendered in other files such as ASP or PHP.

Comment: @Talmage: At least for PHP, that has nothing to do with HTML but rather with how PHP works. Also the HTML is not rendered in these files. Rather the output of evaluating a PHP file is text, which is interpreted by the consuming program (e.g. the browser).

Comment: Yes but the browser can’t use file extension to determine how to render as the question supposed.  The tag tells the browser to render as HTML rather than some other format.

Comment: It's worth adding that the <html> and </html> *tags* can be omitted in an HTML document (but not an XHTML document), and the html element will still be present as the root element. So, whether or not you specify the tags, the root element will always be there, for the reasons given in this answer.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. The `<html>` tag is the root and can even be omitted in somes cases (from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/html)):

> The start tag may be omitted if the first thing inside the `<html>` element is not a comment. The end tag may be omitted if the `<html>` element is not immediately followed by a comment, and it contains a `<body>` element either that is not empty or whose start tag is present.

But not only:

- It can be styled with CSS (though styling the `<body>` will usually be enough).
- It can have global attributes, especially `lang`, which is the [W3C way of defining an HTML document language](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-language-declarations).

There is probably more to say but that’s what I see as arguments for the `<html>` element, apart from its main role of being the root element for an HTML document.